# Converting a propositional logic formula to CNF (Conjunctive normal form)

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have a propositional formula that I have to convert to CNF and then write that in abreviated clausal form.  I feel like i'm making a mistake somewhere but struggling to figure it out.  Any idea what I am doing wrong here/what i'm missing?

my attempt:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WsHf.jpg

Comment: You are dropping brackets all over the place.  Keep them up until you don't need them.

Comment: You are reading $((p \land q) \lor r) \to (p \to (q \land r)) \to \lnot q$ as $\Big(((p \land q) \lor r) \to (p \to (q \land r))\Big) \to \lnot q$ rather than the usual reading of $((p \land q) \lor r) \to \Big((p \to (q \land r)) \to \lnot q\Big)$.  Are you sure that was what was intended?

Comment: @Graham Kemp  I think I understood it in the second way.  Might have added parenthesis in the wrong place...

Comment: Then it might be best to start over from the beginning, and take more care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(q\vee r\vee\neg q)$ is a tautology, as is $(q\vee\neg r\vee\neg q)$.  Neither is equivalent to $r$.

There also seem to be a few more errors due to dropped parenthesis, and I'm not sure you're reading the nested implication correctly.  $A\to B\to C$ is normally understood as $A\to(B \to C)$.